# Testing custom routes in rails 3.0.1 does not work, or is it me?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, functional-testing

For some reason when I run this functional test

```
require 'test_helper'

class ListControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should get mylist" do
    post :mylist, :format => :json

    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
SomeApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  match "/mylist" => "list#mylist", :method => "POST"
end
```

list_controller.rb

```
class ListController < ApplicationController
  def mylist
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json  { render :json => []}
    end
  end
end
```

[Sourcecode as a gist](https://gist.github.com/f7d12b3ef7486bbae01d)

I get this error:

```
1) Error:
test_should_get_mylist(ListControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"list", :format=>:json, :action=>"mylist"}
/test/functional/list_controller_test.rb:6:in `test_should_get_mylist'
```

Any ideas?

Regards,

Michal

Comment: Is there a route for it? We can't see your route file.

Comment: It was there as a link to gist. Added routes.rb to the post directly

Comment: is the misspelling in your assert also in your real code?

Comment: What misspelling? I can't see anything wrong with that. Please, point it out for me Joel.

Comment: "repsponse" is the typo.

Comment: Sure, it was just a type. Thanks though. I just corrected that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I got it. Those stupid errors are the most difficult to spot. Sometimes I cry for ruby to have strong typing ;)

the problem is in the routes.rb. Instead of:

```
match "/mylist" => "list#mylist", :method => "POST"
```

it should have been

```
match "/mylist" => "list#mylist", :via => :post
```

Thanks everyone who tried to help me.